# EGit Push: How to store the remote repository info

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

When i'm pushing new commits to the remote repository in Eclipse i have to complete the form again :

[image]

But even if i click on the check box store in secure store, then info are not stored.

How could i store the info to not have to retype it each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you always use only one single remote repository, then you should [configure that remote repository to be your "upstream"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pushing_to_other_Repositories). Select a project and use Team -> Remote -> Configure push to upstream.

If you want to use multiple remote repositories, then you should expand your repository node in the git perspective to see the *Remotes* node. [You can add a new remote repository there](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Adding_a_Remote_Configuration) once (using the context menu on the *Remote* node) and afterwards push to one of your remote repositories by just selecting the matching remote remote node and use the *Push* command from the context menu of the remote node.

[image: new remote configuration]